# connecting to network registry

Tags: c#

In Windows you can launch the registry and them connect to another registry; does anyone know how to accomplish this in c#? or if you know how of an api call that would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API function is [RegConnectRegistry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724840%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I've linked to the MSDN documentation, where you'll find a list of all Registry Functions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try suggestion about half way down on this page: http://vbcity.com/forums/p/42161/170595.aspx

You will need the proper permissions on the machine, of course.